# python 3.0 - Import file within the given directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, file-management

I am trying to to import a file within this folder's directory. The file name is ChessEngine.py in the directory shown below:

```
C:\Users\tquig\OneDrive\Desktop\Chess
```

my code for importing the said file is:

```
from Chess import ChessEngine
```

Then I create the environment using:

```
gs = ChessEngine.GameState()
```

with class:

```
def GameState()
```

I am receiving a no module named 'Chess' error in powershell when calling python ChessMain.py.
Could I be importing my file all wrong in python 3?

Comment: Your Chess folder should have an `__init__.py` file to be a module that python can import from.

Comment: I do contain a _init_.py. I forgot to mention that. Is there supposed to be any required code in it? At the moment it is blank.

Comment: I think that's fine. Perhaps (as other answers in the link suggest), you might need to add the directory to your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: How would you go about constructing a python path?

Comment: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/4909087).